# Permissions of all files and directories in /usr

Tags: permissions, sudo, chown, pkexec

Oh my.. I just did a terrible mistake: `chown -R root:root /usr`. Mea [maxima] culpa..
I fixed `sudo` and `pkexec` already, but I want to be sure, there is no "sleeping" issue waiting on me in the future.

Could anyone please find out using simple command, what files / directories have 'special' permissions? I know about `/usr/bin/sudo`, `/usr/bin/pkexec` and `/usr/lib/policykit-1` only. Thanks..

I'm using Debian 11..

Comment: Potentially there are many more. And deamon in sbin may use other permissions. And local may have own user). In general: do not change anything in the distribution domain. And never give root user without knowing the files, it is a security problem. Now maybe some process gained root. How to solve: reinstall (force reinstall also with same version) packages

Answer (score 6):

In Debian, most files under `/usr` [are supposed to be owned by `root:root`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#permissions-and-owners); your `chown` shouldn’t have broken your system beyond repair, as far as *ownership* is concerned. In particular, `sudo`, `pkexec` and `/usr/lib/policykit-1` are owned by `root:root`.

However, as you determined, `chown` also clears “special” permissions (setuid etc.), which is what `sudo` and `pkexec` lost.

To restore the expected permissions, reinstall all your packages:

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat '${binary:Package}\n' |
xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install
```

or, if you want to avoid upgrading to the current version of any of your installed packages,

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat '${binary:Package}=${Version}\n' |
xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install
```

Comment: Thanks.. It seems chown is not implemented correctly, because the command 'chown root:root' should ignore all files which are owned by 'root' and which belong to the 'root' group and it does not.. It changes the permissions too e.g. from (-rwSr-xr-x 1 root root /usr/bin/sudo) to (-rwXr-xr-x 1 root root /usr/bin/sudo)!!!

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot about that! When ownership is changed, “special” permissions are cleared... I’ll fix my answer.

Comment: These dpkg* oneliners are simply brilliant.

Comment: [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html) "_Unless chown is invoked by a process with appropriate privileges, the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of a regular file shall be cleared upon successful completion_" is it not reasonable therefore to expect the OP's command to have left intact the setuid/setgid bits?

Comment: @roaima on current versions of Linux, [`chown` clears the bits even for `root`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html).

Comment: @StephenKitt Could be the following issue caused by wrong permissions too? 'gnome-session: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 512   gnome-session: libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate'. I reinstalled libegl-dev w/ the same result. When I execute the helpers w/ the '--print-renderer' parm I get 'lvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 128 bits)%'. Any idea??